# Django custom template without form.as_p

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I am trying to implement custom password reset form in Django. I got my custom template loaded and functionality worked using `{{ form.as_p }}`

However, I want to use my own fields instead of `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Here's my form,

```
<form method="post" action="/accounts/password_reset/complete">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>New Password</label>
    <input type="password">
    <label>Re-enter new password<label>
    <input type="password"</input>
    <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
</form>
```

However, on submission it gives me `Method Not Allowed (POST) 405` error. Am I missing on something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like ohlr said,

Add the `id` attribute. To compare with {{ form.as_p }}. I would recommend using the Chrome elements inspector to get the values of the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the **id** attributes in the inputs in your  template.. without those the form can not relate which input is wich variable in the Backend.

Compare the **as_p** form with your form than you'll get the right id names